# MySql Select Destinct with two tables and by Timestamp

Tags: mysql, select, timestamp

I want to select Info by timestamp and UnitID. Heres the two tables:

Table Info:

```
 ID | UnitID |       Time            | Info   
 -----------------------------------------------
 1  |  101   |  2011-07-20 08:22:02  |  info 101
 2  |  102   |  2011-07-21 08:22:02  |  info 102
 3  |  103   |  2011-07-22 08:22:02  |  info 103
 4  |  104   |  2011-07-23 08:22:02  |  info 104
 5  |  104   |  2011-07-25 08:22:02  |  info 104
 6  |  102   |  2011-07-26 08:22:02  |  info 102
```

The results I want is one for each UnitID and latest Time (timestamp) for this UnitID as:

```
 ID | UnitID |       Time             |  Info   
 ------------------------------------------------
 1  |  101   |   2011-07-20 08:22:02  |  info 101
 3  |  103   |   2011-07-22 08:22:02  |  info 103
 5  |  104   |   2011-07-25 08:22:02  |  info 104
 6  |  102   |   2011-07-26 08:22:02  |  info 102
```

How do I make this Query?

Comment: Please don't make the formatting worse, user872497. Rolled back to Harry Joy's version. Also, don't edit it [thanks and greetings](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.ID, t1.UnitID, t2.MaxTime, t1.Info
FROM Info t1
INNER JOIN (SELECT UnitID, MAX(Time) As MaxTime 
            FROM Info
            GROUP BY UnitID) AS t2
ON (t1.UnitD = t2.UnitID AND t1.Time = t2.MaxTime)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one -

```
SELECT t1.* FROM table1 t1
JOIN (
  SELECT UnitID, MAX(Time) maxtime FROM table1 GROUP BY UnitID
) t2
ON t1.UnitID = t2.UnitID AND t1.Time = t2.maxtime;
```

Change 'table1' with an actual table name.

Comment: Thanks for all the quick answers! Got it to work with cularis!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this?

```
SELECT * FROM Info GROUP BY UnitID HAVING Time = MAX(Time);
```